# Apache OFBiz; Issue

Tags: tomcat, erp, ofbiz

The following is the issued i encountered:

https://localhost:8443/accounting/control/main  this URL is working
https://127.0.0.1:8443/accounting/control/main  this URL is working
https://w2019-dc:8443/accounting/control/main   this URL is not working with the following message | ERROR MESSAGE
org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandlerException: Domain w2019-dc not accepted to prevent host header injection 
https://192.168.1.254:8443/accounting/control/main    this URL is not working with the following message | ERROR MESSAGE org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandlerException: Domain w2019-dc not accepted to prevent host header injection

I need your advise.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add w2019-dc (or any other used domains) in the host-headers-allowed list property in security.properties file.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-11583 and https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-12425 for details

Comment: The problem is that My router has a dynamic IP Address it keeps of Changing every time. Is there any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: There it says no wild cards is allowed, Is it possible to allow any IP Addresses? Or run this Platform Dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

If your domains names follow a pattern it's possible for you to add the necessary unless you are unable coding. Then better create an OFBiz Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/OFBIZ?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin%3Asummary-page